# Codecademy Python lesson: It's Okay to be Average

Tags: python, list, dictionary, average

I'm stuck with this excercise:

```
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

# Add your function below!

def average(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if lst[item] == float:
            print sum(lst[item]) / len(lst[item])

average(tyler)
```

Why can't I get all three averages printed out?
Does the loop break when it gets to a string key in the dictionary?
How can I get only float averages printed out?

Comment: I think Codecademy also has a Q&A forum? No?

Comment: The keys are not floats. Hence the if-statement is always false.

Comment: `tyler` is not a list, so it is confusing to call is `lst` when it's an argument of the `average` function. `for item in lst` yields the `dict`'s keys.

Comment: What do you think `lst` is here? Perhaps you wanted to call `average` for each of the *values* in the `tyler` dictionary instead?

Comment: Yeah, what's that `lst[item] == float` supposed to do?  `float` is a _type_ object, and none of your values is a _type_, they are all lists of floats.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. I'm very new to programming so you really cleared some thing up for me. `lst` is an argument, that was given in the excercise description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if lst[item] == float:
```

This line looks in the dictionary for lst[item] - however all the values in your dictionary are either strings or lists. Hence, the value of the logical expression above is always False.

Instead, use:

```
if type(lst[item]) == list:
```

I also think if you are going to iterate over a dictionary, not calling it 'lst' would be better.

```
def average(lst):
    return sum(lst)/len(lst)

for key, value in tyler.iteritems():
    if type(value) == list:
        print average(value)
```

Comment: Since the thing I commented on isn't there anymore, I removed my comments altogether.  Feel free to do likewise.  It will tidy up SO a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

You might wanted to check if the current item is a list or not. You can do it with [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) function, like this

```
def average(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(lst[item], list):
            print sum(lst[item]) / len(lst[item])
```

**Output**

```
51.0
100.0
46.0
```

Remember we cannot guarantee the order of the keys in a dictionary. So, the order in which the averages are printed might be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
def average(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if item != 'name':
            print sum(lst[item]) / len(lst[item])
```

This means that you'll compute and print the average as long as the item is not `'name'`. You've named your variable `lst` but it's actually a dictionary. So you can update the code to works as follows (which is more readable):

```
def average(person):
    for key, value in person.items():
        if key != 'name':
            print sum(value) / len(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the you expecting,

```
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

# Add your function below!

def average(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if type(lst[item]) == list:
            print sum(lst[item]) / len(lst[item])

average(tyler)
```